# bulk mails with php, limit is 300 emails/hr, what is 1 email?

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, bulk-email

Its just a knowledge question. We have the server limit of sending 300 emails/hr.

I am confused for what is 1 email considered as.

Lets say I send a single mail through SMTP with 20 users(in bcc/cc/to), will it be counted as one email or 20 ?

If anybody know, how many users can be included in just one mail either through "to" or "cc" or "bcc", is there any limit for this too???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your host could interpret it differently but if you send to 20 addresses the server has to actually send the email 20 times, once for each address. It just isn't possible to send one email for the whole list since chances are slim that all of your addresses are on the same server. You can't send to a gmail server and expect hotmail address to get the mail. See what I mean? That is how I would interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

It varies per host- you need to contact your web host for their policies.

If you are looking to do a lot of emailing, I hear that RackSpace has no upper limit on emails/ recipients.  Something to look into